# Why was my question "A car rental company automatically pleads guilty, and pays a fine without letting me defend myself. Am I liable?" closed as dupe?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Law Stack Exchange post: [A car rental company automatically pleads guilty, and pays a fine without letting me defend myself. Am I liable?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/66793/a-car-rental-company-automatically-pleads-guilty-and-pays-a-fine-without-lettin)

Why was this closed as duplicating [Can a rental car company require you to forfeit your right to fight a fine?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/63891)?

I wrote

> My case can be distinguished from
> [Can a rental car company require you to forfeit your right to fight a fine?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/63891)
> was asked for Florida. Ontario's laws obviously differ.

The second distinction is that Enterprise CarShare is [car sharing, not car rental](https://availcarsharing.com/resources/car-sharing-vs-car-rental). Alas, my case is probably less successful because I will have had more time and opportunity to peruse the contract.

Comment: I agree with you, these questions are different due to the different jurisdictions involved.  I've voted to reopen, as have three others.  I anticipate your question being reopened soon.

Comment: And yet the only answer you've received explicitly stated it does not apply in Ontario.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: It would be problematic to store separate instances of the same question for every jurisdiction of interest.

While (AFAIK) we haven't established "rules" on this matter, we *have* established the custom of encouraging *answers* that address a different jurisdiction than the one specified in a question.  The corresponding custom for questions is to discourage posting a separate instance for every jurisdiction of interest.

Here are relevant Meta discussions:

- [Same question on two jurisdictions: 1 or 2 questions?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/10)
- [How do we handle localization of questions/answers?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/10)
- [Why don't questions with jurisdiction specific answers need to specify their jurisdiction?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/308/10)

Answer (score -4):

This is an [ongoing problem](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/dale-m-stop-deleting-answers-which-are-not-yours) with that moderator. But nowadays pointing that out prompts him to allege [democracy (though with not all votes having equal weight)](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1061/18505) or [personal abuse](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1277/18505). And providing a number of [specific, verifiable examples](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/978/revisions) of his censorship is simply [flagged as spam or offensive](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/978/18505).

The mod not only should have refrained from unilaterally closing your question, but he should have paid attention to [your improvement/edit](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/66793/revisions) instead of him being adamant about keeping it closed.

Even if [his comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/66793/a-car-rental-company-automatically-pleads-guilty-and-pays-a-fine-without-lettin?noredirect=1#comment140227_66793) preceded(?) your edit, the rush to censor content --such as your question-- departs from the essence of *moderation* and from what he wrote back when he was [pursuing mod privileges](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/872/18505) ("*I am always open to the possibility that my understanding is wrong [...] I would err on the side of leaving questions open for the community to decide what to do.*").

The mod had posted an answer to where he redirected you. There is nothing wrong with him redirecting the audience to a post *he* answered (it is natural for us to do that because we keep "fresher" in our mind the answers we ourselves author). The problem is that he coupled this with censoring your post, a decision which is disproportionate to the "harm" (if any) a duplicate question can cause.

Altogether what we see now is in contrast to the time when [all [...] moderators explicitly committed to minimalist/*laissez-faire* moderation](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/311/18505). But I'm glad to see that at least @RyanM's [comment](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/why-was-my-question-a-car-rental-company-automatically-pleads-guilty-and-pays#comment3221_1287) on this post as well as his vote to reopen your question drift from his [recent stance](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/dale-m-stop-deleting-answers-which-are-not-yours#comment3210_1275) that a moderator's "*voice is worth more*" than ours.